# Can a JPQL JOIN be made not to make multiple SQL queries?

Tags: sql, jpa, join, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Take a common business situation in which you have a table of `orders` with a *created_date* and a *customer_id*.  You want to read all the orders this month along with the associated customer so:

```
@Query("select Q from Order Q join customer C on Q.customer_id=C.id where Q.created_date >= '2021-11-01'")
```

This works but when I added to `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

I was horrified to observe that for each order, the customer details are re-read with a separate `select` statement;  thus, if there are say 80 orders this month, the JPA system executes 81 `select` statements, not one.  I appreciate that this might be hard to optimise-out in the general case but it makes the system useless for production.  Is it possible to give hints to JPA/Spring to avoid the extra `select` statements?

Answer (score 1):

This answer works for me and makes sense.  If you're JOINing two tables then the resultant rows are of a new type, distinct from the type of the rows of the underlying tables.  So you have to declare that type:

```
data class OrderwithCust (
    var orderid: Int,
    var customerid: Int,
    var customerName: String?
)
```

You can then obtain a list of `OrderwithCust` instances via

```
@Query("select new OrderwithCust(Q.id,Q.customer_id,C.name) from Order Q join customer C on Q.customer_id=C.id where Q.created_date >= '2021-11-01'")
```